# Hamiltonian cycle and Euler Cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

When $G = K_n, n \ge 3$ and  $n$ is odd, then from the edges of the $G$ can be built edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles.
Is it true?

Comment: Are you saying that we are looking for multiple hamiltonian cycles that are edge dijoint from eachother?  how many?  or just more than 1?

Comment: @user3440448: Probably $(n-1)/2$ of them such that every edge of $K_n$ is in one of the Hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: yes i can see that this is true.  specifically, for $K_{2n+1}$ there are exactly n edge disjoint hamiltonian cycles.  I'm not sure how to prove it yet...